# How to get Review from placeId Google Place API

Tags: android, google-places-api

hope someone could help me.

I am trying to get the number of reviews given the placeID on Android. Google Places API used to support this call, but it seems that is not longer included in the API. Does anybody knows how could I get this value?

Note: I have the place rating, I need is the total reviews count.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rating of particular place by using the **Google Place API** using as below:

```
PlaceBufferResponse places = task.getResult();
Place myPlace = places.get(0);
Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + myPlace.getName());
Log.i(TAG, "Place ratings found: " + myPlace.getRating());
```

for more information about **[The Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details)**

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I am already fetching the rating with Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById, but the Reviews are the one I cannot find how to get it from the API.